# get select option attribute value reactive form

Tags: angular

Hi I`m using Angular 6 reactive.

This is select control

```
<select _ngcontent-c2="" class="floating-select ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="user" value="" ng-reflect-name="user">
   <option _ngcontent-c2="" value="adduser" ng-reflect-value="adduser">--Add User--</option>
   <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
      }-->
   <option _ngcontent-c2="" value="1: gokulanathan.s" ng-reflect-ng-value="gokulanathan.s" usrstatus="ACTIVE">gokulanathan.s</option>
   <option _ngcontent-c2="" value="2: subin.abraham.ext" ng-reflect-ng-value="subin.abraham.ext" usrstatus="ACTIVE">subin.abraham.ext</option>
   <option _ngcontent-c2="" value="3: subin.abraham.ext" ng-reflect-ng-value="subin.abraham.ext" usrstatus="INACTIVE">subin.abraham.ext</option>
   <option _ngcontent-c2="" value="4: manoj.g.ext" ng-reflect-ng-value="manoj.g.ext" usrstatus="ACTIVE">manoj.g.ext</option>
   <option _ngcontent-c2="" value="5: rajesh.augustine" ng-reflect-ng-value="rajesh.augustine" usrstatus="ACTIVE">rajesh.augustine</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to get "usrstatus" attribute value with formcontrol

This is my formBuilder code

```
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      clientid: ['', Validators.required],
      user: ['', Validators.required],
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      status: ['', Validators.required]       
  });
```

I`m looking for something like this..."this.form.controls["user"].usrstatus". please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the `this.form.controls["user"].usrstatus` and I don't think it's possible to get attribute value like this (correct me if I am wrong)
but you can have the change event on select

```
<select _ngcontent-c2="" class="floating-select ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"
formcontrolname="user" value="" ng-reflect-name="user" (change)="getAttributeValue($event)">
```

and in you component

```
getAttributeValue(event) {
    const selectEl = event.target;
    const attrVal = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].getAttribute('usrstatus');
    console.log(attrVal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think it impossible to get second value from select option like this.

first please change formcontrolname to formControlName.

than in your option value set
value='{"user": "1: gokulanathan.s", "status": "ACTIVE"}'

you can create new class or interface to receive those 2 values or you can use JSON.parse method and access your values like this:

JSON.parse(this.form.get("user").value).user;

JSON.parse(this.form.get("user").value).status;

you can read more about formControlName here:
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName

Comment: control value I`m able to get, can i get option attribute value

Comment: i edit my answer, if you want to get it from the control and not by raising events which also works this is the best way i can think of.